# docker project accessing mysql container

Tags: mysql, docker, laradock

I am using Laradock at the moment to run various PHP projects -- and while I know it has a MYSQL implementation, I also have mysql container already running, which I have several databases in and can already hit externally with Sequel Pro. I have been attempting to link this so Laradock and its projects can see and use this container but with no luck. I tried adding the below to the Laradock docker-compose.yml and while it doesnt error I also cant seem to get my PHP project to use the linked db. Am i missing something?

```
### MySQL ################################################
    mysql:
      image: mysql:5.6
      external_links:
        - myContainerName
      ports:
        - "3306:3306"
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
```

Comment: Show full docker compose file, you need to link the App container to the database container

Comment: @Borjante the yml file is massive, I'm using laradock. here it is, I think I'd need to link the "workspace" to my db container. do i need to add "external links" to that portion? that starts on line 47 https://github.com/laradock/laradock/blob/master/docker-compose.yml